# Установить содержимое системного буфера обмена

Tags: java, rest, test-automation, appium

В буфер обмена добавить текст определенной структуры.

В appium документации есть метод [Set Clipboard](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/clipboard/set-clipboard/index.html).

Пример из документации:

```
driver.setClipboard("label", ClipboardContentType.PLAINTEXT, base64Content);
driver.setClipboardText("happy testing");
```

Что должно лежать в системном буфере:

```
mockNetwork

--> GET https://имя_сайта:цифрки/api/auth/client/exists/phone/+79006541971
<-- 200 {"result":false}

--> POST https://имя_сайта:цифрки/api/auth/client/register
<-- 200 {"phone_token":"токен","phone_token_lifetime":300,"result":true,"token":"токен"}

--> PUT https://имя_сайта:цифрки/api/auth/client/register/confirm
<-- 200 {"result":true}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В capability указать:

```
caps.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
```

После объявления driver указать:

```
driver.setClipboardText("happy testing");
```

Работает только в связке с automation